# Azure Dev Ops - Importing a Work Item as a bug

Tags: csv, ado

Does anyone have an example of a csv doc that allows you to upload a BUG as a work item to ADO.
Emphasis is on Work Item being a **BUG.**

I have tried this using and keep getting error:

Work item 0 Field 'Type' cannot be empty.
Please correct the unsaved work item(s) and try again.

My CSV below:

```
Work Item Type,Title,Description,Repro Steps,Area Path,Iteration Path,Severity
Bug,Sample Bug Title,Sample Bug Description,Steps to reproduce the bug,Project\Team\Area Path,Project\Team\Iteration Path,3. Severe
```

Comment: Bumping this :)